# Why am I obtaining high MAE values when constructing my deep neural network

Tags: tensorflow, keras, neural-network, regression, hyperparameters

I am trying to do hyperparameter optimization for a regression problem using a deep neural network.

I am getting slightly high MAE values (5-7) when in the literature this is around 0.9-5 (using the same dataset to train the NN).

Any idea of what I could improve? I can provide the dataset if needed, but it's very large.

X looks like this:
[image]

Y looks like this:
[image]

X is composed of 865432 rows=features and 134 columns=samples where rows are ordered by decreasing pearson correlation with variable Y which is the age of each sample (a float variable).

Each entry in X is a number between 0-1.

Since there are too many features for the number of samples I decided to take only the 40000 most important features. (Also because I don't know how to include feature selection within the training of the model).

Here is the loss vs epochs:

[image]

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense

from scikeras.wrappers import KerasRegressor
import keras.losses
from keras import backend as K
import keras_tuner as kt
from keras_tuner.tuners import RandomSearch

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score

def dynamic_model(hp):
    # hyperparameters (independent of number of layers)
    # Number of hidden layers: 1 - 50
    hp_num_layers = hp.Int("num_layers", 2, 10)
    hp_learning_rate = hp.Choice("learning_rate", values=[1e-2, 1e-3, 1e-4])    
    
    # Initialize sequential API and start building model.
    model = keras.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(CpG_num,)))
        
    # Tune the number of hidden layers and units in each
    for i in range(1, hp_num_layers):
        
        # hyperparameters (dependent on num_layers):
        hp_units = hp.Int(f"units_{i}", min_value=100, max_value=400, step=100)
        hp_dropout_rate = hp.Float(f"dropout_{i}", 0, 0.5, step=0.1)
        hp_activation = hp.Choice(f"act_{i}", ['LeakyReLU', 'PReLU'])            
        
        model.add(
            keras.layers.Dense(units=hp_units, kernel_initializer='normal', activation=hp_activation)
        )
        model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(hp_dropout_rate))
    
    # Add output layer
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(units=1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
    
    # Define optimizer, loss, and metrics
    model.compile(
        optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=hp_learning_rate),
        loss=loss_function, 
        metrics=metrics
    )
    
    return model

def correlation_coefficient_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    x = y_true
    y = y_pred
    mx = K.mean(x)
    my = K.mean(y)
    xm, ym = x-mx, y-my
    print(type(mx))
    r_num = K.sum(tf.multiply(xm,ym))
    r_den = K.sqrt(tf.multiply(K.sum(K.square(xm)), K.sum(K.square(ym))))
    r = r_num / r_den
    r = K.maximum(K.minimum(r, 1.0), -1.0)
    return (1 - K.square(r))

loss_function = 'mae'
metrics = ['mae', correlation_coefficient_loss]
scoring_function = 'neg_mean_absolute_error'
tuner_kind = 'random'
results_dir = '../tmp_files/Grid_Search_results/'+name+tuner_kind
hp = kt.HyperParameters()

if tuner_kind == 'random':
    tuner = kt.RandomSearch(
        dynamic_model,
        objective = 'mae',
        overwrite=True,
        directory = results_dir,
        project_name = 'random_tuner_trials',
        max_trials = 500
    )

tuner.search(
    X1[name],Y1[name], 
    epochs=50, 
    validation_data=(X2[name],Y2[name]),
)

best_hps=tuner.get_best_hyperparameters(num_trials=1)[0]
best_hps_model = dynamic_model(best_hps)
best_hps_model.fit(X1_train[name],y1_train[name],validation_data=(X2_train[name],y2_train[name]), epochs=500, batch_size=10)
```

Comment: Can you please provide more info on your dataset? In case of having numerical data, do you normalize it before feeding it into the model?

Comment: Also, before getting to the hyperparameter optimization, what is the behavior of loss vs. epoch for a single (reasonable) architecture?

Comment: I added some information and will try to also analyze loss vs epoch soon.

Comment: I added the loss vs epoch, I also changed the activation function to 'LeakyReLU' or  'PReLU' which significantly improved the performance.

Comment: I could not understand from what model architecture you obtained the loss-epoch plot. Regardless, I'd suggest to start off with the architecture from the literature that you mentioned performs well ("I am getting slightly high MAE values (5-7) when in the literature this is around 0.9-5"). If you cannot reproduce their work with the same model, your feature selection may be the culprit.